Video game taking up 4TB of disk space
For context, I do own a 4TB HDD but this game is stored on my 512GB SSD and was running smoothly up until recently. Now my HDD is showing as almost full even though I am still able to store large files in it.
How do I fix this or is there any need to fix this anyways?


The size reported for an application has been historically inaccurate. The size for this particular application obviously is inaccurate. There is nothing to solve.

This size indicator is useless and often wildly inaccurate. If you want to know what’s taking up space on your PC, you need to use a disk space analyzer like WinDirStat or WizTree or TreeSize.

@DanielB thanks bro I will do that.

@Ramhound I got it thanks!
